# Android Work manager get triggered everytime I open my app

Tags: android, performance, android-workmanager

I have made a periodic work manager and its misbehaving heavily. Instead of doing a work in the set interval it executes it every minute.
And it also gets triggered everytime i open the app. This means if I open my app 50 times in a minute , It does the work 50 times.
Here is my code

```
public class UpdateUserDataService extends Worker {
    public UpdateUserDataService(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
        super(context, workerParams);
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken().addOnSuccessListener(s -> {
            DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Update");
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy_h:mm a", Locale.getDefault());
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            String currentDate = dateFormat.format(c.getTime());
            JobFooter jobFooter = new JobFooter(currentDate, s);
            reference.child(dateFormat.format(new Date())).setValue(jobFooter);

            Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            notificationIntent.putExtra("Notification", true);
            notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0,
                    notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            NotificationHelper notificationHelper = new NotificationHelper(getApplicationContext(), defaultSoundUri);
            Notification.Builder notificationBuilder = notificationHelper.getNotification("Title", currentDate, intent);
            notificationHelper.notify(10, notificationBuilder);
        });
        return Result.success();
    }
}
```

And in my main activity under oncreate method

```
 Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder()
                .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
                .setRequiresBatteryNotLow(true)
                .build();
        PeriodicWorkRequest periodicWorkRequest = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(
                UpdateUserDataService.class, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .setConstraints(constraints)
                .build();

        WorkManager.getInstance(this).enqueue(periodicWorkRequest);
```

All I want is my code to execute after every 15 minutes followings OS norms and constraints and irrespective of my app getting opened or not.

Comment: One minute trigger is not possible since the [Docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/define-work) say the minimum interval is 15 Minutes

Comment: That i know but it really happened with me.

Comment: How to solve the retriggering of work on app opening?

Comment: Just try adding an `Application Class` and then move the code for triggering the work from MainActivity's onCreate() to Application Class' `onCreate()` method

Comment: Shifting the code in application class does not help either. It gets triggered everytime I open the app.

Comment: @AnkitVerma Any solution for this?

Comment: @SumitShukla Yes I did found the issue here. The thing is every time I opened the app it created a new Periodic Work and launched it.  I am posting the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String EXPIRY_CHECK = "unique_worker_name";

 Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder()
            .setRequiresBatteryNotLow(true)
            .build();
            
PeriodicWorkRequest periodicWorkRequest = new PeriodicWorkRequest
      .Builder(UpdateUserDataService.class, 1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
      .setConstraints(constraints).build();
            
WorkManager.getInstance(this)
      .enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(EXPIRY_CHECK, ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP, periodicWorkRequest);
```

This will check if an already existing worker is initialised or not and will not launch a new worker if it is already running.

Comment: But everytime when app is launched, it runs doWork() block again.